# Should a kind of determiner be used before the word "unit"?

Tags: grammar, determiners, countable-nouns

Please look at the following sentence. I wouldn't say this that way and would consider a kind of determiner that should be used before the word **"unit"**.

What about you please?

> *Sort the telemetry records by **unit** number.*

Comment: The sentence you quoted is idiomatic, just as you might say "sort the records by age".

Comment: What do you mean by idiomatic please? I've heard it so much. Would you state its definition in simple words and briefly?

Comment: An idiomatic phrase is one that 'sounds right' to a native speaker. [Have a look at definition 1 in this link](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/idiomatic).

Answer (score 2):

In this instance, the complement of the preposition **by** is a *category* or the name of an *attribute* and thus  no determiner (aka "zero" determiner) is the right choice.

Just as in an apartment complex each apartment has a unit number (they all possess that attribute), the telemetry records in your example have been assigned a unit number.

> The students were grouped by age.
>
> She opened the outer doll, and then the doll inside it, and then the doll inside it, until she had all of the dolls before her; she then arranged them by height.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I see what you say but can't figure out what it has to do with my instance! PS: Both _age_ and _height_ are commonly uncountable so there is no need to use a determiner for them!

Comment: @franky: What's the age of that piece of furniture? It looks like an antique. What's the height of that building?